# Cell Returns Validation Error Reference when any cell in that row contains a validation Error

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am looking for assistance in developing a google sheets formula or script that returns the Cell Reference of any cells (in that Row) that contain a validation Error.

For example in Row 1, Cells B1 and E1 contain validation errors. I would like to return the following in A1.

A1 = "Validation Error in Cell(s) B1, E1"

Each row contains 50+ columns so individually checking each validation in a formula is not practical.

Answer (score 1):

#### Find validation errors:

This may require some modification depending upon you unique siutation.

```
function cellerrors(ra1 = "A1:M1") {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  const rg = sh.getRange(ra1);
  const ri = rg.getRow();
  const ci = rg.getColumn();
  const vs = rg.getDisplayValues();
  let o = vs.map((r, i) => {
    let row = [];
    r.forEach((c, j) => {
      let cv = sh.getRange(ri + i, ci + j).getDataValidation().getCriteriaValues();
      cv[0].unshift('');
      if (!~cv[0].indexOf(c)) {
        row.push(`Valid Values: ${cv[0].join(',')} Row: ${ri + i} Col: ${ci + j} Error - Value: ${c}`);
      } else {
        row.push(`Valid Values: ${cv[0].join(',')} Row: ${ri + i} Col: ${ci + j} No Error - Value: ${c}`);
      }
    })
    return row;
  })
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(o));
  sh.getRange("A2").setValue(o.flat().join('\n'));
}
```

[image]